# Excel-vba pull filtered information from user-chosen workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I have to make a master report that compiles information from two somewhat big workbooks. These workbooks change weekly, but the information structure in each one is and will always be the same, right from how many columns to each column name (how many records each one has might vary, of course, from 20000 to 25000, etc.)

From Workbook 1, I have to pull information from specific columns from a range. Through investigation I managed to find a nice piece of code that helped me a lot. The information spans from A:W in the worksheet, but I just need information from columns c, f, g, i, and w.

```
Private Sub BtnImportDPr_Click()
Dim wkbCrntWorkBook As Workbook
Dim wkbSourceBook As Workbook
Dim rngSourceRange As Range
Dim rngDestination As Range
Set wkbCrntWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Excel 2007-16", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsa; *.xlsb"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show
        If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
            Workbooks.Open .SelectedItems(1)
            Set wkbSourceBook = ActiveWorkbook
            Worksheets("SysSummary").Activate
            ActiveSheet.Range("A:W").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<=700" _
            , Operator:=xlAnd
            Set rngSourceRange = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select source range", Title:="Source Range", Default:="SysSummary!C:C,SysSummary!F:F,SysSummary!G:G,SysSummary!I:I,SysSummary!W:W", Type:=8)
            wkbCrntWorkBook.Activate
            Set rngDestination = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select destination cell", Title:="Select Destination", Default:="B:F", Type:=8)
            rngSourceRange.Copy rngDestination
            rngDestination.CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit
            wkbSourceBook.Close False
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

This code allows the user to choose the workbook he/she wants to work with, I know it looks a risky with lots of potential errors, but I am sure that the structure of the range I am pulling information from will remain the same since once it is changed it will probably means this work utility will be nonexistent.
|||

Now, with the second workbook I need to work with a table (which across all the workbooks the user will choose, its name will remain the same). The table is big, from columns A to AQ, but I just need information from columns a, e, u, p, q, v and aa.

So, since the last code worked I tried using it again but some errores popped out. Like, a table is different.

```
Private Sub BtnImportTTS_Click()
Dim wkbCrntWorkBook As Workbook
Dim wkbSourceBook As Workbook
Dim rngSourceRange As Range
Dim rngDestination As Range
Set wkbCrntWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Excel 2007-16", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsa; *.xlsb"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show
        If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
            Workbooks.Open .SelectedItems(1)
            Set wkbSourceBook = ActiveWorkbook
            Worksheets("Sys_DETAIL").Activate
            ConvertTableToRange
            ActiveSheet.Range("A3:AT").AutoFilter Field:=27, Criteria1:="02"
            Set rngSourceRange = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select source range", Title:="Source Range", Default:="Sys_DETAIL!A:A,Sys_DETAIL!E:E,Sys_DETAIL!U:U,Sys_DETAIL!P:P,Sys_DETAIL!Q:Q,Sys_DETAIL!V:V,Sys_DETAIL!AA:AA", Type:=8)
            wkbCrntWorkBook.Activate
            Set rngDestination = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select destination cell", Title:="Select Destination", Default:="B:H", Type:=8)
            rngSourceRange.Copy rngDestination
            rngDestination.CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit
            wkbSourceBook.Close savechanges:=False
        End If
    End With
End Sub

Sub ConvertTableToRange()
Dim rList As Range

With Worksheets("TTS_DETAIL").ListObjects("Table_TRACK_TTS.accdb")
    Set rList = .Range
    .Unlist                           ' convert the table back to a range
End With

End Sub
```

After investigating a bit, I decided to go the lazy route and just convert the table to a normal range through vba code, and it worked. But for some reason, I cant pull all the information. After filtering to Criteria1: 02 (which is extremely important) I am left with 8500 records (from 200000 that used to be), but Excel just pulls 5000 records.

I am not sure if it has something to do with the fact that the range used to be a table. So, if someone can help me modify my code or give me a new one that works with table I will very much appreciate it.

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Range("A3:AT").AutoFilter` seems like it might be a problem...

Comment: The Problem with this very basic approach is you end up opening complete source workbook, and if your source workbook is having significantly bigger size then the main problem will come when you try to copy a large range, as first it gets stored in clip board and excel might not respond after that if memory usage crosses the limit... I had similar job and I first approach was exactly the similar as yours, which didn't worked for me. so I had to do it with VBA-SQL.... and if your source data file is not that big then I think your code is very over complexed...

Comment: Then how can I simplify it? I am relatively new to VBA

Comment: how does size of your source file varies? how much it is now?
In my case it became unpractical to do it by simply opening the source workbook and copy pasting columns.. then I had to use VBA-SQL approach. [Here](https://analysistabs.com/excel-vba/ado-sql-macros-connecting-database/)

Comment: For the first workbook, which pulls information from a range: before filtering there are over 200000 records, after filtering to 02 I pull 22000 records. For the second workbook, which pulls information from a table with a name that won't change: before filtering there are over 180000 records, after filtering I get 8700 records.